# 413 Request Entity Too Large EM Slideshow

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, slideshow

I'm using EM Slideshow Compact Extension, when i try to upload an image (1,10MB) and save the slideshow it gives me a 413 error: Request Entity Too Large.
Any solution?